# How to properly combine function and list generator?

Tags: python

As I know list generators are a little bit quicker than using `.append()`. So I was just interested how could I implement this code, but using the generator. All that matters is that I need to get list in the end.

this is the original script:

```
x=4
def factorial(n):
    f=1
    list = []
    for n in range(1, n+1):
        f = f * n
        list.append(f)
    return list
testList = factorial (x)
for i in range(x): print(testList[i], end = ' ')
```

I've tried this:

```
f=1
n=4
def fun(n):
    f=f*n
    return f
testList = [fun(f) for n in range(1, n+1)]
```

and this is definitely not the way to do it (the program says that in function `f` is not declared. and overall... just tried this to test)
also tried this:

```
testList = [lambda f : f*n for n in range(1, n+1)]
```

but all I got this way is the list of functions. I could get the factorial still, but not the way it should be.

This is a little bit problematic for me because there is a buffer variable (`f` in the original script).

Comment: Typo? `fun(n) for n in range(1, n+1)`

Comment: @Carcigenicate em... yes. Translation problems(english is not native)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can implement it in this way, with usage of `global` keyword:

```
f = 1
n = 4

def fun(n):
    global f
    f = f * n
    return f

testList = [fun(n) for n in range(1, 10+1)]
print(testList)

# [1, 2, 6, 24, 120, 720, 5040, 40320, 362880, 3628800]
```

Comment: This implementation would fail as long as the input `n` is not called in the exact order of `1, 2, 3, ...`. It can only be used for generating the list once.

Comment: @GZ0 you are right. Also I want to admin that the speed up is too small to be significant. There is no practical task where you need more that 1000 factorials and 1000 factorial can be generated instantly with any implementation.

Comment: The problem itself may not be of much practical use. But there are other similar tasks such as computing cumulative sum / product of a list of numbers.

Comment: @sanyash factorials are just an example. I'm just curious, could I do this without .append()? I was once told that global warming and inefficient code are indirectly related. So I found that idea pretty interesting and search for solutions from time to time. Even if it's not that big deal by itself, and even if it's python(which is not the best in that terms)

Comment: @Jofumi Accessing global variables has performance overhead. The solution is actually less efficient and takes 50% more time in my tests than a simple `append`. The deleted generator function answer using `yield` is much cleaner IMO and slightly more efficient than `append`.

Comment: @GZ0 I was sure the deleted answer with generator using `yield` must be accepted answer, I personally liked it much more than mine.

Comment: @GZ0 well, things to learn. I still got the info about the new feature in 3.8 and that using yield is better idea. Thank you. Just a little bit of shame I can't check two or more answers for being accepted as all of them complement each other.

Answer (score 3):

In the upcoming Python 3.8 scheduled to be released next month, the new assignment operator `:=` makes it possible to generate the sequence using a list comprehension:

```
p = 1
output = [(p := p * i) for i in range(1, n + 1)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You're first example is nearly there, you just need to make two tweaks:

- You need to pass in `n` rather than `f` to `fun`.
- You need to use `global` to make sure that the `f` you refer to in the function is the `f` declared outside of the function. Otherwise, `f` will not be updated on each iteration of the list generator.

```
    f=1
    n=4
    def fun(n):
        global f
        f=f*n
        return f
    testList = [fun(n) for n in range(1, n+1)]
```